# CSS IE only conditional

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I tried adding a conditional css style for Internet Explorer but it isn't working.
I've tried

```
<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">nav{letter-spacing:.5px}</style><![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]><!--><style type="text/css">nav{letter-spacing:.5px}</style><!--><![endif]-->
```

Neither work.

The blog is http://costumingdiary.blogspot.com

Notice the links at the top of the page. They fit okay in Chrome, but IE widens the letter spacing too much. In Chrome, the link text is centered with extra spacing on either end. In IE, the text stretches all the way across to fill the space. If I change "About" to "About Me", the text will overflow to a second line in IE but not in Chrome.

Any help to set the conditional please? Thanks.

UPDATE: The fact that IE10 doesn't support conditionals is the big reason why I've given up on this. There is no simple css way to fix this. Adding javascript has proven to much for me. Actually adding javascript defeats the purpose of me removing (by way of adding comment tags) as much "unremovable" Blogger imposed script from my blog as possible. I guess I'll have to live with the stretched-to-the-max IE text. :(

Comment: What are you using to build the site? Also, the stylesheet links are not in the page.

Comment: I'm using Blogger. Stylesheet links not on page?

Comment: If you expect that code to be on the page, it is not there. What is your experience with web languages?

Comment: Your #1 code should work in IE9, [IE10+ don't support conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), IE<9 don't support `nav`.

Comment: Ugh, I've been designing web pages for years. I don't have the above code in the template right now because it isn't working.

Comment: IE10+ don't support conditionals? If this is true, then that explains everything.

Comment: Will try the div instead of nav now. Disappointing if it ends up working because I really like the html behind-the-scenes "look" of nav.

Comment: Hm. Still not working with the div. The second line of the original code in my question squishes the text down on both Google and IE. The first line does nothing.

I do have the stylesheet to load first, then the general .nav style to load second, then the IE to load third. So the IE line should override any styling for the first two, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below conditional for anything below IE9:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="path" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="path" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

If you want to target other versions of IE you can [**look here**](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/).

**--EDIT--**

You will need to add a HTML5 polyfill to enable support for the `<nav>` element on IE8 and below.

You could use [**Html5shiv**](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) or [**Modernizr**](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr)

Comment: I tried that link in css-tricks before I posted here. It didn't work either. I'll try it again one more time to triple check now.

Comment: You could try `nav{letter-spacing:.5px !important}` to check the override is working. Or try something simple like changing the `<body>` background colour just to test.

Comment: Oh yeah. Now I know why I didn't use that page. He wants me to use an external css stylesheet. I already have one. What I want is to add a one line of code outside the stylesheet to adjust for the spacing for IE only.

Comment: I did try to make sure the override is working. When I add the style code without the IE, it works just fine, though it squishes my text on Chrome too.

Comment: What version(s) of IE are you testing? It looks fine to me in IE.

Comment: IE10. Yeah, it looks fine but the text is wide compared to Chrome. Actually, I wanted the first link to read "About Me" but had to shorten it to "About" just so it fits in the IE browser. If I change it back to "About Me", then the links will overflow to the next line in IE.

I could keep the link wording as is to avoid the situation, but it frustrates me NOT knowing how figure this out.

Comment: Changing the `<nav>` padding to `padding: 10px 0;` should fix that, or at least slightly smaller.

Comment: That will change it for all browsers. I just want the change for IE browsers.

Comment: If you only want to target IE10 you could [try this](http://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/).

Comment: Oooo Jamie, that looks interesting. Will try that now.

Comment: I tried adding the script in a <script> after the html tag. Also tried adding it to the html tag itself. All it does is display the script. Doesn't execute for me. Does anyone know how the code in the link above should look? I'm not that good with javascript. I hope I don't have to convert the script to escape characters. If I do, then I'll just leave all this be. *sad*

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that conditional comments syntax is wrong? See [full description](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) of comments syntax,  in your example all is right.

I get html source code from your link - there is no conditional comments where, but has big html comment with script which contains encode conditional comments(!)

Comment: I added the comment conditionals to REMOVE the unnecessary Blogger code they force on on .blogspot blogs. There is no way to remove Blogger code and script unless you surround it with comment code. Makes my page load at least 30 seconds faster than allowing the unremovable Blogger script to load.The original conditional I mentioned in my question isn't on the page because it doesn't work.

Comment: 30 seconds faster OMG!!! It loads fine for me, check your site out on http://webpagetest.org or pointers to speed up your page. Target 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Your Body CSS rule has a letter-spacing:1.2px; That determines the spacing between your characters. I am looking at the page in Internet Explorer and Chrome and the fonts seem to render pretty closely to me. Also do not assume font rendering between platforms is consistent. If you develop on a MAC for example, they use a completely different font rendering sub-system than Windows for example. So test Chrome on the same system as IE. Also do NOT assume IE 8 is the same as IE 9 is the same as IE 10 or 11.

```
body {
background-color: #294A63;
color: #000;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
letter-spacing: 1.2px;
line-height: 1.4;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 960px;
min-width: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

}